# Why the task didn't delete from local storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a problem when I press on delete task (x symbol) It deletes from UI and then go to search the local storage to delete it from there . The function of deleting from storage works fine and i checked it by console The only problem in comparing the text of task in UI and text of task in tasks array that comes from local storage : they are the same and both are strings but it still doesn't work and when you reload the page the tasks still on it and it didn't deleted from the local storage

https://codepen.io/mokai2008/pen/jdxeXJ

```
// When click  delete the task

taskList.addEventListener('click', removeTask);

function removeTask(e) {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('remove')) {
    if(confirm('Are You Sure?')) {
  e.target.parentElement.remove();
      // Remove from LS
      removeTaskFromLocalStorage(e.target.parentElement);
    }
  }
}

// Remove from LS
function removeTaskFromLocalStorage(taskItem) {
    let tasks;
    if(localStorage.getItem('tasks') === null){
      tasks = [];
    } else {
      tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
    }

    tasks.forEach(function(task, index){
      if(taskItem.textContent === task){
        tasks.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });

    localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
  }
```

Comment: Did you debug? `console.log(index, taskItem.textContent, task)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your solution.

To directly answer your question, the reason it doesn't delete is because when you add the task to the HTML in your `addTask` function, the `textContent` of the element ends up being `'task '` (notice the extra space at the end).

Quick fix:

```
if(taskItem.textContent.trimEnd() === task){
    tasks.splice(index, 1);
}
```

The next problem is that you are splicing the array you are iterating over! This will cause the index to get messed up and you will skip the next item after the one that is spliced.

For example:

```
let x = [1,2,3,4,5];
x.forEach(function(item, index) {
    if (item === 3) {
        x.splice(index, 1);
    }
    console.log(item); // prints: 1, 2, 3, 5
});
```

The simplest way to get around this:

```
tasks = tasks.filter((task, index) => taskItem.textContent.trimEnd() !== task);
```

Comment: Big thanks I got it the space after 'task ' . I didn't notice at first time I read your solution and I have used trimEnd() and it worked fine. Now I deleted the space it worked fine. Thanks again